# How do you fill a List<Request>() for a BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest to update multiple rows/columns/cells in a google spreadsheet in C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets, console-application, google-sheets-api

```
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest requestBody = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
requestBody.Requests = new List<Request>();

Request r = new Request();
requestBody.Requests.Add(r);
r.UpdateCells = new UpdateCellsRequest();

var gc = new GridCoordinate();
gc.ColumnIndex = 0;
gc.RowIndex = 0;
gc.SheetId = 0;

r.UpdateCells.Start = gc;
r.UpdateCells.Fields = "*";
r.UpdateCells.Rows = new List<RowData>();

// TODO:: loop through record set to update cell data (cd) with values to insert
SqlDataReader reader = default(SqlDataReader);
reader = o_cSQL.RunSPReturnDataReader("Shipments", 40997, sNow, sNow);

while (reader.Read())
{
    var rd = new RowData();
    r.UpdateCells.Rows.Add(rd);

    rd.Values = new List<CellData>();

    var cd = new CellData();
    cd.UserEnteredValue = new ExtendedValue();

    // the next line is only updating the first cell (first row/first column) 
    // how to you get multiple CellData created for a single row ?
    cd.UserEnteredValue.StringValue = reader["new_attn"].ToString();
    rd.Values.Add(cd);
}

SpreadsheetsResource.BatchUpdateRequest batchRequest = service.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(requestBody, spreadsheetId);
batchRequest.Execute();
```

Can someone please help with how you get multiple cells updated per row ?

I know I'm only showing one value from my 'reader' from the database, that's where I got stuck in that I don't know how to specifically pinpoint each cell of my spreadsheet. I'm pulling an unknown recordset size from a database and need to enter it on a google spreadsheet.  I know how many columns.

Comment: nm, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Since I know my columns, I just kept making new `CellData();` items for each `RowData` item in my `reader.Read()` while looping. Worked first time!